# MySQL Trouble Inserting Data into Form

Tags: php

I am trying to submit some data to my mysql database, however nothing is appearing. Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

PHP File after Submitting Form:

```
$db_name="database";
$tbl_name="messages";

session_start();
$from= $_SESSION['username'];


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get data that sent from form 
$to=$_POST['to'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$date = date('m/d/Y');

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(to, from, message, subject, date,read)VALUES('$to', '$from',                  $message', '$subject', '$date',0)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Note: Server is working. Database Name: database  Table Name: messages

Comment: what the result of your return value?

Answer (score 2):

`to` and `from` are [**reserved words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) which must be wrapped in backticks.

```
(`to`, `from`, message, subject, date,read)
```

It's best to not choose those words if at all possible.

Plus, a missing quote in `$message'` change to `'$message'`

```
('$to', '$from', '$message', '$subject', '$date',0)
```

Also remove the quotes in:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

to:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Using error reporting.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Plus, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use `mysqli_*` with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo)

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: so...many...corrections :)  Take all the suggestions in this user3496349.  You need to read up more on PHP+MySQL security practices.

Comment: I keep these extra notes handy for such an occasion @Devon It saves from retyping it all over again; there are so many who use plain text passwords, it's mind-boggling.

Answer (score 0):

echoing your query by adding this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(to, from, message, subject, date,read)VALUES('$to', '$from',                  $message', '$subject', '$date',0)";
die($sql);
```

gives me this:

```
INSERT INTO messages(to, from, message, subject, date,read)VALUES('', '', ', '', '04/08/2014',0)
```

there's a quote missing there from 'message'... change this line:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(to, from, message, subject, date,read)VALUES('$to', '$from',                  '$message', '$subject', '$date',0)";
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, why is that from colored blue. Does this have a reference to a command in mysql? Communicating with my other database's work fine however I don't use the word "to" or "from"

Comment: they're reserved words. SO must do something to that, I didn't make it blue... also, filter your code before you use it at least ($subject=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"subject",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) to prevent code from being inserted in your MySQL DB (as per @Fred's remark). The code you have there is highly vulnerable for infections!

Comment: Most definitely! Since I'm running on a local WAMP server it shouldn't be a problem but when posting live I definitely will need to revise my communications and prevent sql injections.